# Android WebView touch event link

Tags: android, click, webview, touch

I have a webview with a banner and when I click on the banner there should open a second webview that follows the link. How can I do that? I have created the first WebView and it shows my banner but when I click on it, it opens the link in the same WebView.

How can I catch any events in the WebView when I click on a link that it should do something (with that link)? Just like [`shouldStartLoadWithRequest` in iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:).

Thank you,

Wouter

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can monitor events in a `WebView` using a [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html).  The method you want is [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)).  This allows you to perform your own action when a particular URL is selected.

You set the `WebViewClient` of your `WebView` using the [`setWebViewClient()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebViewClient(android.webkit.WebViewClient)).

Comment: how to use shouldOverrideUrlLoading() ? please give short sample code.

Comment: Got the solution... It write like this                             "private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         System.out.println("DDD URL: "+url.toString());
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }"

Answer (score 1):

`shouldOverrideUrlLoading` good method, but if you click on `current` link `webview` client not calling to `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method.